# Is there a secure way of allowing users of my app to selectively share data from an external service?

Tags: encryption, public-key, keys, zero-knowledge-proofs

Is there a secure way of allowing users of my app to selectively share data from an external service with my app?

In order for the users of my app to get their personal data from the external service they need a private key for the external API.

Is there any secure method of allowing the user to share some of their data from the external service without having the user expose their keys with my app?

I thought perhaps end to end encryption could be a potential solution. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can the user "just" fetch the data from the API themselves, filter / transform it appropriately and then provide it to the app? Are you worried about your app learning the authentication key or your service backend learning the authentication key?

Comment: Yes this is the concern ... "service backend learning the authentication key?" Obviously I want the app to be able to get this data in an automated way.